# Circles changing (radius) and position in time with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I need again your help.

I am trying to plot 4 circles with a defined radius and a defined distance between them. The distance and the radius change in time. The first two circles should be concentric and the remaining two too.

Since i want to make an animation with this, I need that the middle point of the distance between the circles is plot at the origin (0,0)

So my file looks like this

```
time radius1 radius2 radius3 radius4 orb-sep
  1      1       1       1      1       1
  2      2       2       1      1       2
  3      2.1     2.2     1.5    1.02    3
  4      1.6     2.1     1.4    1.01    2.5
  ...     ...    ...     ...    ....    ...
```

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To plot the circles use the `circles` plotting style. To calculate.the x-position use the expression `using (-$6*0.5):...`, which uses half of the negative value in the sixth columns a x-value. Selection of the plotted value during the iteration can be done with `every`:

```
unset key
do for [i=0:9] {
plot 'file.txt. using (-0.5 * $6):(0):2 every ::i::i with circle,\
    '' using (-0.5 * $6):(0):3 every ::i::i with circle,\
    '' using (0.5 * $6):(0):4 every ::i::i with circle,\
    '' using (0.5 * $6):(0):5 every ::i::i with circle
    pause 1
}
```

Comment: thank you very much! I'll check it soon, but it seems straightforward.